# WebView does not render the correct width and does not render at all without a height property on React Native 0.63

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I use React Native 0.63 on Android with TypeScript, no expo and, worth mentionning, react-native-orientation-locker.

I made an Embed component like this:

```
const Embed: FC<Props> = ({ embed }: Props) => {
  const { width, height } = useDimensions().window
  console.log(`WIDTH = ${width}`)
  // Return 411

  const getSource = (embedCodeOrURI: string): (WebViewSourceUri & string) | (WebViewSourceHtml & string) => {
    if (embed.startsWith('http')) {
      console.log(`DEBUG > Embed > returned { uri: ${embed}}`)
      return { uri: embedCodeOrURI } as WebViewSourceUri & string
    }
    console.log(`DEBUG > Embed > returned { html: ${embed}}`)
    // If I use the test content, I still need to specify the height in the style prop but the width adjust correctly
    const test =
      '<div style="background-color:red"><p style="font-size:32pt">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p></div>'
    // Using the wrapper or not has zero impact on the bug
    const withWrapper = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head></head>
            <body>
              <div id="baseDiv" style={max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%}>${embedCodeOrURI}</div> 
            </body>
           </html>
        `
    const html = withWrapper
    return { html } as WebViewSourceHtml & string
  }

  if (!embed) {
    console.log(`ERROR > Embed > embed = ${embed}`)
    return null
  }

  return (
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={getSource(embed)}
      scalesPageToFit={true}
      containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 800 }}
      allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
      onError={(syntheticEvent): void => {
        const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
        console.warn('ERROR > Embed > WebView error: ', nativeEvent)
      }}
      onHttpError={(syntheticEvent): void => {
        const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
        console.warn('ERROR > Embed > WebView http error: ', nativeEvent.statusCode)
      }}
      onRenderProcessGone={(syntheticEvent): void => {
        const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
        console.warn('WebView Crashed: ', nativeEvent.didCrash)
      }}
      onContentProcessDidTerminate={(syntheticEvent): void => {
        const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent
        console.warn('ERROR > Embed > Content process terminated: ', nativeEvent)
      }}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      renderLoading={(): ReactElement => <ActivityIndicator />}
    />
  )
}

export default Embed
```

First strange thing, the Twitter or Instagram embeds I tested displays in 411 width:

[image]

Second strange thing, If I use useDimensions().window.width (=411) as a the containerStyle width, this does no change.

...But if I add width=600, the view scale.

[image: 600]

Third stange thing, the test html does displays full width if I don't specify a width.

[image: Test html]

...and will scale out of the screen if I specify 600:

[image: 600]

Forth strange thing, if I do not add a height in the container view, the html content don't displays at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue of the different scales by adding this in the head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">\
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

I still need to specify a height so I currently adjust this manually for each post in the database.